# Changing Cntrl + R shortcut for Running scripts in R Windows GUI

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts

Is is possible to change the "Control + R" shortcut for sending scripts from the R text editor in the Windows GUI to the R console?  I'd like to change it to "Control + Enter" to be more like the shortcut on my Mac.  I do all my normal work on a Mac but have to use R on a PC to interface with some PC-only computational software.

Additional tidbits:

- I'd rather not run an IDE on the PC if I don't have to, though perhaps this is the solution.
- I use `Rstudio` on my Mac, but `Rstudio` does not get along with the PC software I'm running

Comment: Out of idle curiousity - what software doesn't play nicely with RStudio on Windows?

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is to download the R source, hack it (see line 625 of `src/gnuwin32/editor.c`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/gnuwin32/editor.c ), and build a new R binary yourself (see the R for Windows FAQ for the tools you need to build from source).  I hope someone else comes up with an easier solution ...

Comment: I'd go with an external editor, many of which have macros or configs to allow you to execute a `source` command in R for the selected text.

Comment: Following up @Andrie's comment: the RStudio support guys are generally *very* responsive -- if you went to the RStudio support forums and told them about a conflict you were having they might help you out.

Comment: The program MARK, used for mark-recapture analysis of wildlife data (ie, birds banded with unique ID numbers), doesn't seem to like running via RStudio.  I run MARK via the package RMark, which bundles the data, design matrices etc up  and sends them to MARK, which I believe was written in Fortran.  MARK sends back a bunch  objects in lists to R.  I haven't worked to hard too get RStudio to communicate with MARK.  The analyses take long enough to run already I figured it is easier to cut out the middle man.

Comment: So `RMark` doesn't operate properly under RStudio on Windows?  You might also to the author (Jeff Laake) about that -- taking a quick glance at the code, I see that there's some hard-coded stuff in there about `if (.Platform$GUI[1] == "RTerm")` that might be fairly easy to modify ...

Comment: Adding Jeff Laake's comment: "Not certain what problem you are having with RMark in RStudio. I don't use RStudio much but just tried RMark/MARK and it worked fine under RStudio. I have 2 colleagues that use RMark with RStudio and I've not had any problems reported.

Please describe what is or is not working and any error messages you are getting."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is:
  **"No, there are no [built-in] ways to alter the menu shortcuts in the R Console"**

I'm however gathering here -community wiki style- some of suggestions posted as remarks to this questions.

One approach may be to download the R source, hack it (see circa line 625 of [**src/gnuwin32/editor.c**](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/gnuwin32/editor.c): ), and build the R binary anew (see the R for Windows FAQ for the tools you need to build from source).  This seems to be a rather radical approach for the mere convenience of using an alternate keystroke sequence...

A similar approach may be to create an automatic patcher program which would patch the R executable, by locating the byte patterns surrounding the compiled logic of editor.c mentioned above and replacing it with a byte sequence for the desired keystroke.  This solution may be sensitive to changes in the binaries, but also avoids the build process altogether...

An easier way to achieve this is probably by using an  external text editor. Most modern editors have macros or configs that can be used, for example, to execute a source command in R for the selected text.

Comment: See in particular http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/projects/Editors.html . (I have to say that the binary patch approach sounds much scarier to me than rebuilding R from source ...)

Answer (score 1):

Customizing keyboard shortcuts is made available in Rstudio 0.99.644.
See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts for more information.